# How to Render an xml tile grid in java

Tags: java, xml

So i decided to write my games data files in xml since a lot of people recommend it security wise for an online game, but how exactly does one render an xml tile grid in java?

format will be as follows:

```
<Data>
   <Tile X="1" Y="1" Value="12"></Tile>
</Data>
```

Comment: People recommend XML *security-wise*? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does the `Value` mean?

Comment: Tile type as in like if value = 12, it's a grass tile

Answer (score 2):

XML is just a data storage (or transfer) format. The XML file itself has nothing to do with rendering tilemaps. You actually need to have the data in memory in a better format suited for rendering tile maps.

I think you should tackle the problem from another direction. Rather than trying to figure out how to render XML data as tile map, you should just [learn to render tile maps](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=java%20tile%20map%20tutorial), and then save that data in a XML file.

Comment: So kinda like having a tile map in a image file and have an xml file have the information on what each color pixel represents?

Comment: You must have the tilemap data in memory somehow when you are rendering it. After you are able to render the tilemap, you can save the data you rendered the tilemap with in a XML or some other file format for future use.

Comment: Do you have any where that can teach me that or a place I can go to study how to do that? Like a YouTube video or website?

Comment: There is bunch of links about rendering tilemaps in java behind the link in my answer. I could just do a quick google search for reading and writing xml files in java too, but you are better off learning how to do google searches yourself.